# How to find out the index of the record in which it is being written

Tags: delphi

I have variable

```
MyList : array [1..5] of TMyRecord;

type
    TMyRecord = record
    private
      FSize : Integer;
    procedure SetSize(const Value: Integer);
    public
      property Size : Integer read FSize write SetSize;
    end;
```

In this variable I write multiple times, to different indexes.
How do I find out the index of the record in which it is being written during procedure SetSize?

Comment: "How do I find out the index of the record in which it is being written during procedure SetSize?" Not possible with the definitions as presented here.

Comment: @Martin I told you before: Do NOT change this question, since you have received answers. The change may invalidate those answers. So do as I told, post a NEW question! I reverted your question to what it was originally.

Comment: @Tom Ok. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom Sorry. I prepared better explanation and post new question. In that it isn't THE SAME RECORD. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026232/how-to-get-value-from-field-of-superior-record-when-it-is-setting-property-of-su?noredirect=1#comment113218870_64026232

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the code that writes to a record of `MyList` makes the choice of which record it writes to. E.g. you probably have some code like this:

```
MyList[2].Size := 31000;
```

Your implementation of `SetSize()` is obviously:

```
procedure TMyRecord.SetSize(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FSize := value;
end;
```

Within the `SetSize()` procedure it is not possible to know the index, and I don't really understand why it would need to know. In fact, the record doesn't even know (neither needs to know) that it is a member of `MyList`

Comment: My original record has more fields; and change of one field (FSize) could affect another field of that same record. But I don't know the value that another field.

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice. I tried better explain my task.

Answer (score 1):

If, and only if, `SetSize()` has access to `MyList`, then it can figure out the index for itself by looping through `MyList` looking for the element that matches its `Self` pointer, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMyRecord.SetSize(const Value: Integer);
var
  index: Integer;
begin
  for index := Low(MyList) to High(MyList) do
  begin
    if @MyList[index] = Self then
    begin
      // use index as needed...
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I do not recommend this approach, but it is *possible*.

A better solution would be to pass the desired index to `SetSize()`.

You could pass it in as an input parameter to the `Size` property, eg:

```pascal
type
  TMyRecord = record
  private
    FSize : Integer;
    function GetSize(const Index: Integer): Integer;
    procedure SetSize(const Index, Value: Integer);
  public
    property Size[Index: Integer] : Integer read GetSize write SetSize;
  end;

var
  MyList : array [1..5] of TMyRecord;

...

function TMyRecord.GetSize(const Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  // use Index as needed...
  Result := FSize;
end;

procedure TMyRecord.SetSize(const Index, Value: Integer);
begin
  // use Index as needed...
  FSize := Value;
end;

...

MyList[SomeIndex].Size[SomeIndex] := 31000;
```

Again, not very clean, but *possible*.

I would suggest storing the index as a member of the record instead, if possible, eg:

```pascal
type
  TMyRecord = record
  private
    FIndex : Integer;
    FSize : Integer;
    procedure SetSize(const Value: Integer);
  public
    property Index : Integer read FIndex write FIndex;
    property Size : Integer read FSize write SetSize;
  end;

var
  MyList : array [1..5] of TMyRecord;

...

procedure TMyRecord.SetSize(const Value: Integer);
begin
  // use FIndex as needed...
  FSize := Value;
end;

...

for I := Low(MyList) to High(MyList) do
  MyList[I].Index := I;

...

MyList[SomeIndex].Size := 31000;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the first solution sounds me best. My original record has more fields and change of one field (FSize) could affect another field of that same record. Change of field FSize take place many times in my program and I don't want  looking for all of them. I thought that using property "Size" allow me capture each ocurence of change FSize and check/update value of second field of this record.

Comment: How does changing one field affect the other fields? Adding a new field for the index would not change or invalidate any uses of the existing FSize field. I think you need to edit your question to show the actual code you are actually having trouble with.

Comment: Better emphase that the `index` variable should not be used outside of the loop. :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for you help. I tried better explain my task.